# Certificate authority SSL using AWS load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb, certificate-authority

I have a frontend and backend server on different web hosting,
I used Netlify for hosting frontend and AWS for hosting backend
when I connected frontend with backend give me error : Mixed Content Error (Http/Https)

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.frontend-domain.net/' was loaded over
> HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
> 'http://domain-eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com'. This request has been
> blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

because frontend uses https but backend uses http.(http://domain-eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com).
I use loadbalancer to connect to my ec2 instance(backend).

the question is :
how i make loadbalancer(domain-eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com) uses https and add certificate ?
is it free ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how i make loadbalancer(domain-eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com) uses https and add certificate ?

You need **your own domain**. You can't use `domain-eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com` because this is AWS-owned domain, not yours. Once you get your domain, you can get **free** SSL cert from AWS ASM.

> is it free ?

There are some free domain providers. You can try that. But for anything serious, its better to actually buy something.

Comment: it's perfect , thanks alot
but I still have a problem , now I have ssl domain but when I route to my instance , not working
when I route from http domain to Ec2 my instance or load balancer it works
but when i route from https domain to my instance or load balancer it's not working however in acm page this domain is certified and status is issued
and also i'm sure that security group is right

Comment: @OmarGhanim I would suggest making new question with specific details of your LB and listener setup.

Comment: yes , I already did =>[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69595368/route-from-https-domain-to-loadbalancer-aws)