# Route from https domain to loadbalancer AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53, amazon-elb, certificate-authority

I have ssl certificate for ex:

> `domain.com` , `www.domain.com` , `*.domain.com` , `server.domain.com`

and the status is Issued and every things ok in ACM AWS
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhBdS.png)
but when I route this ssl https://server.domain.com to my loadbalancer ; it is not working
but when i route from http ; it's working
also I tried too much in security groups and loadbalancer listeners and make sure it allows for http/https  but still have the same problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RniUj.png)

Notice : loadbalancer created by eks cluster and service port => 5000:30385

Comment: `it is not working` what response do you get? Or you cannot connect at all?

Comment: almost i get `This page isn’t working If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 408` 
and sometimes get `This site can’t be reached` @gusto2

Comment: HTTP 408 error is a timeout. So its probably either a firewall rule blocking access, or your instance is not listening on port 443 but is listening to 30961. Do you have a certificate installed on your ec2 instance on port 443? If not, try setting your HTTPS _instance_ port to 30961 (this is called "SSL offloading" - this is generally "secure enough" as you control all traffic inside your VPC). It is also possible to use a self-signed cert on the ec2 instances to allow TLS between instance and load balancer, or a paid cert(but you cant use ACM on the instances themselves).

Comment: thank you so much @MisterSmith , my loadbalancer is created by eks , so it's classic load balancer by default ; when I migrate it to Application load balancer (ALB) and setting the instance port and listeners and target group then it works !!
I really appreciate your help. Thank you.